# Date conversion in python pandas.read_excel

Tags: python, date

I have an excel file which has two columns
 column1 = "Jan-01" 
 column2 = "2009"

I want to know how to build a converter/ any function that reads the above two columns and give me string as 01/01/2009 (Day/Month/Year)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKGN4.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you want to use the pandas package for that? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not knowing what to do, i just tried pd.read_excel('./filename.xlsx')

Comment: So you have a pandas dataframe (it is not very important where it comes from, Excel seems to be irrelevant here)! Try to play with, try to give an example of it, try try try ....

Comment: Answers are for the worthy. Not for the needy. Show your efforts.

Answer (score 1):

you can read both columns as strings and the combine those and parse to date,for eg. if your excel file is

```
day&Month   Year    data
Jan-01      2009    1
Jan-02      2009    2
Jan-03      2009    3
```

assuming you have only one shhet on your excel file, do

```
df = pd.read_excel('path\yourexcel.xlsx',dtype={'day&Month':str,'Year':str},parse_dates={'Dates':[0,1]})
print(df)
  Dates          data
0 2009-01-01     1
1 2009-01-02     2
2 2009-01-03     3
```

Comment: Thanks, for your reply